# Using Wildcards in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Wildcards are cool.

I am trying to do this:

```
$route["(:any)/controller"] = "controller";
```

basically, I want to put the wildcard in the front. It doesn't quite work, and I don't know any work around.

Comment: Can you comment further on what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to send all requests to a specific controller, or anything with /*/controller to /controller? Because (:any) is very greedy and will redirect pretty much everything, which may break other parts of your app.

Comment: Thank you for responding, basically i want to have something like this: /project_name/controller/action , but i don't know how to achieve that. regex...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using regular expressions did the trick.. thank you for pointing out (:any) is greedy!

```
$route['([a-z_A-Z]+)/controller'] = 'controller';
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work. If it doesn't try shuffling around your route definitions to put the wildcard line at the end.

Also I don't think you need the parenthesis around `:any`.